# Permission system using PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, permissions, roles

I'm developing an admin dashboard with different areas, where different users may have different permissions. For example:

- News

  - John: edit, view, add, remove;
  - Carlos: edit, view;
  - Mario: --;
- Support

  - John: view;
  - Carlos: edit, view;
  - Mario: edit, view, add, remove;

The way I control this permission is via JSON array, containing each area and list of permission. I save this in my MySql database (serializing first) and also on the localStorage. This way I can check on the frontend but also make a final validation on the server side, via PHP.

JSON example:

```
{
    "area": "news",
    "permission": [
        {"field": "access", "value": true},
        {"field": "read", "value": true},
        {"field": "edit", "value": true},
        {"field": "add", "value": true},
        {"field": "remove", "value": true}
    ]
},
{
    "area": "support",
    "permission": [
        {"field": "access", "value": true},
        {"field": "read", "value": true},
        {"field": "edit", "value": false},
        {"field": "add", "value": false},
        {"field": "remove", "value": false}
    ]
},
...
```

---

I'm with doubts about this system because, first, I never did anything like this and didn't found any example, so I don't know if this is the proper way to do this. Also, I'm storing this as JSON because there are admin users who need to edit (with checkbox) this permissions, so it's easier to display this on the frontend.

But I'm very open to change this method based on other criterias you think it's better. I just want to have it security first and also easy to maintain.

Comment: Maybe you should look at some questions in SO about ACL and RBAC to help you design your JSON. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acl+rbac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am by not way an expert on these kind of matters, I'm just sharing how me and my senior are doing our current project.

**Database:**

Your design looks solid enough, but I would think about how I would hold these permissions in a table.

lets say we have a `users` table

```
user_id | name | password
-------------------------
      0 | John |     ****
```

I can see 2 possible ways you would extend our database to hold these permissions.

You can add permission columns that tell what each user can do

```
user_id | name | password| perm1 | perm2 | ... |permn
------------------------------------------------------
      0 | John |     ****|     Y |     N |     |    Y
```

That will entail having a lot of columns and a messy design. on the plus side you will have the granularity to dictate exactly what one can and cannot do.

You can however add the concept of `roles` to your design.

You can make a `roles` table, define the types of user roles (and the kind of permissions they provide) in your application and just give each user a role

```
user_id | name | password|  role_id
-----------------------------------
      0 | John |     ****|        1
```

And the `roles` table

```
role_id | role_name  | perm1 |....| permn
----------------------------------------
      0 | Admin      |     Y |    |    Y
      1 | Regular    |     N |    |    Y
```

This way you create a separation of concerns for your users table, instead of placing all your user data into one table that may grow over time (handling dozens of columns in a table is no fun), you can place separate relevant user data across multiple tables. it will also keep your queries short.

(This is similar to how [Java web applications provide privileges/permissions to users](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-users-xml-configuration-example/))

**PHP:**

For your client view, you can hold a session object that describes the current user, you can use the `role` value to tell your php scripts what parts of your templates you want to generate for your user.

Example (blade):

```
@if (user($role) === 'admin')
    <button id="dontclickme">History eraser button</button>
@endif
```

Comment: The problem to create roles is I'll not have custom control for each user permission, or I would have a lot of roles, to match a lot of possible combinations. But I think we can work around your first idea of table, It looks promising! maybe something like: `user_id | area | edit | read | del | add` and then, for each user and each area There would be a better control. What do you think?

Comment: if it's just for permissions then sure. again, consider what will happen when you'll be required to add more features and conditions for a user. that table will bloat in width. what about slightly modifying my 2nd idea? instead of having a table with predefined roles with combinations, have a table with a row of combinations per each user (the primary key would also act as foreign key to `user_id`)

Answer (score 0):

So, Your implementation for the front-end doesn't seem bad to me. You may want to think of how you are going to use the permissions with js specifically, and see if you are happy with the structure of the json based on that.

WRT to the back-end, I try not to store JSON directly in the db.  If you have to do any work on that data directly through the db it will be very inefficient, especially as your number of users grows.

In general with something like this, I would first see if you find something that fits your needs in [composer](https://packagist.org/search/?q=permissions).  If nothing does, you may want to look at a few packages and see if you can find some inspiration if you have doubts of your own implementation.